# Google cloud storage delete directory

Tags: cloud, storage

Hi i try to delete a full repository in the google cloud storage, but i didn't found anything in API about it.
No probleme to remove a single file

```
@Autowired
private Storage storage;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteGcsFile() throws IOException {

    String location = "gs://myPath/my-file.txt";
    GoogleStorageResourceObject gcsFile = new GoogleStorageResourceObject(StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService(), location);

    storage.delete(gcsFile.getGoogleStorageObject().getBlobId());

    return "ok";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the cloud, you could delete a directory using the following function:

```
import { storage } from 'firebase-admin'; //Import storage

const deleteAppletImage = (directory) => {
  const bucket = storage().bucket();
  return bucket.deleteFiles({
    prefix: directory,
  });
};
```

Note that **directory (the function argument)** should  be a string representing the full path of the directory in the bucket. If the directory is the root directory it can be a simple directory name e.g "images".

Also note that I didn't supply any argument to `bucket()`. With that, operations use the default bucket but you could specify the bucket you want to target and that could look like: `const bucket = storage().bucket('target-bucket');`

`bucket()` exposes the same API as the google cloud storage package. You can checkout more about deleting multiple files using the google cloud storage API at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.6.x/Bucket#deleteFiles)